# How do I set an AWS Stack name (for a Lambda Layer) in a SAM Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This page describes how to set a stack name in some AWS console GUI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-console-create-stack-parameters.html

How do I set these values in the SAM Template .yml files?

I'm specifically doing this on a Stack that is only a Lambda Layer if that matters.

I can see that there is some way to do this via CLI as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-creating-stack.html

```
 aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack  --template-url "ssm-doc://arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123456789012:document/documentName"
```

**Is it even possible to set the name in the template?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like stack name is NOT part of the SAM templates. This is done via the command arguments to deploy the stack.

From the same link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-creating-stack.html

> The following example creates the myteststack stack in an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
PROMPT> aws cloudformation create-stack \
  --stack-name myteststack \
  --template-body file:///home/testuser/mytemplate.json \
  --parameters ParameterKey=Parm1,ParameterValue=test1 ParameterKey=Parm2,ParameterValue=test2
```

So when creating the stack, the `--stack-name` argument is how this is set.

The reason I was confused is because I didn't realize where that command was being issued.

Comment: Give an example of the solution you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks @WesleyCheek I hope the update makes this more clear.